# How to drag a file to a drag-zone input element using Playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, file-upload, drag-and-drop, playwright

I have a drag-zone input element for uploading files, and I'm looking for a way to simulate this action using Playwright and TS.
I need to upload many file types such as `txt`, `json`, `png`.

[image]

there is not any mention to this action in Playwright docs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I've found on this [Playwright issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/10667) on GitHub

```js
import { Page } from '@playwright/test';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const dragAndDropFile = async (
  page: Page,
  selector: string,
  filePath: string,
  fileName: string,
  fileType = ''
) => {
  const buffer = readFileSync(filePath).toString('base64');

  const dataTransfer = await page.evaluateHandle(
    async ({ bufferData, localFileName, localFileType }) => {
      const dt = new DataTransfer();

      const blobData = await fetch(bufferData).then((res) => res.blob());

      const file = new File([blobData], localFileName, { type: localFileType });
      dt.items.add(file);
      return dt;
    },
    {
      bufferData: `data:application/octet-stream;base64,${buffer}`,
      localFileName: fileName,
      localFileType: fileType,
    }
  );

  await page.dispatchEvent(selector, 'drop', { dataTransfer });
};
```

Usage Example: (using [this demo-site](https://www.dragdrop.com/test/))

```js
test("simulate drag and drop file", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.dragdrop.com/test/");
  await dragAndDropFile(page, "#demo-upload", "./image1.png", "image1");
});
```